# Scaling bitmaps for each resolution

Tags: android, bitmap, scale, resolution

Is there any method that gets the phones resolution (or dp) and scales bitmaps accordingly? I have all my images in xhdpi folder and at the moment they do not scale the way they should.

I want an efficiant and memory-friendly method that can do the scaling automatically. If not, what is the next best thing? completely new area for me. So any tutorial-link is also appriciated.

this is what I use to load bitmaps atm:

```
public Bitmap loadBitmap(int resourceID) {
    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = true;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap tempBmp = null;
    try {
        tempBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceID,
                options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {

    } catch (Error e) {

    }
    return tempBmp;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if your bitmaps are large, you're much more likely to run into `OutOfMemoryError` on low memory devices if you don't have pre-scaled assets (e.g. for mdpi and hdpi), as the full image still has to be loaded into memory and scaled.

Comment: Im aware :) But do you know if android chooses bitmap according to screen-resolution automatically, so it know wether to pick the bitmap in mdpi-folder or xhdpi-folder? Or does this need to be done in code?

Comment: It will choose it automatically; that's the beauty of the Android resource system. :)

Comment: One more for you, sorry. xhdpi is around 960x720 (according to android.developers). and mhdpi is 470x320. So all I need to do is scale down xhdpi images with 49%x44% and then add it to the mdpi folder?

Comment: Sounds about right, but I wouldn't make assumptions on the display resolution just based off of the density. Should be close but make sure you handle scaling it properly to fit.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) will read through the Supporting multiple screens fully now. Feel like I understand a bit more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna scale bitmap for each phone resolution, you should know phone screen size, scale ratio.

This code will return width (w) & height (h) of screen.

```
DisplayMetrics dMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dMetrics);
float density = dMetrics.density;
int w = Math.round(dMetrics.widthPixels / density);
int h = Math.round(dMetrics.heightPixels / density);
```

activity is instance of Activity which would you like to get screen size.

You have to remember that: When your device is in landscape orientation, w > h. When it in portrait orientation w < h.

So from width & height you can detect your device is in what orientation.

Example:

From w & h of device and ratio (which you want to scale) you can calculate new bitmap size to scale it.

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: So with this I would load my bitmaps using `getResizedBitmap(bitmap, w, h);` (where w & h is from you first code-snippet) ? But I first need to load my bitmaps using my own method, so when is this rescaling best to be called? in `onCreate()` in my view?

Comment: :( You should remember that your bitmap can be large. So if you load it in onCreate() method, your app can be crashed. And you can get OutOfMemoryError. I always use AsyncTask to load Bitmap and load by this way: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: thanks, I think I will end up going with creating bitmaps for each resolution folder. since I have so many.